# Search sub pattern in long string

Tags: php, regex

I have long string below

```
$raw = "bk-pon@huawei-bangrak-fl5.bangkok xpon 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499"
```

and I want to get following substring

```
$Slot = "0/3/0" <- space_value1_slash_value2_slash_value3 
$Port1 = 1 <- the number between last slash and :
$Port2 = 1:4:1.3499 <- the value after last slash until end of string or until found space
```

How can I write PHP to extract $slot, $port and $port2 ?
I think the PHP code should look like following, but I don't know how to write regular expression in xxx, yyy and zzz,

```
$raw  = "bk-pon@huawei-bangrak-fl5.bangkok xpon 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499";

$pattern_slot="xxxxxx";
$pattern_port1="yyyyyy";
$pattern_port2="zzzzzzz";

preg_match_all($pattern_slot, $raw, $slot);
preg_match_all($pattern_port1, $raw, $port1);
preg_match_all($pattern_port2, $raw, $port2);

echo "<br> Slot = ".$slot[0][0];
echo "<br> Port1 = ".$port1[0][0];
echo "<br> Port2 = ".$port2[0][0];
```

Please help me or any good tutorial about this will appreciate.
Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('#\s(\d+/\d+/\d+)/((\d+):\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$#', $string, $matches);
// group 1     ^___________^ ||   |              |
//                   group 3 |^___^              |
//                   group 2 ^___________________^
```

`slot` is in group 1
`Port1` in group 3
`Port2` in group 2

The group number is defined by the count of opening parenthesis.

**Edit according to comment:**

```
preg_match('#^(\S+)\s\w+\s(\d+/\d+/\d+)/((\d+):\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$#', $string, $matches);
```

`email` is i group 1
`slot` is in group 2
`Port1` in group 4
`Port2` in group 3

Comment: Thanks very much. This work. Could you explain how this pattern match to group1, 2 and 3. I need to know logic?

Comment: Could you edit the code to match email in the first wording and discard "xpon" ? so there are total 4 group. and can we assign the group by my own, for example, I want the last parenthesis to be the group1 (array number 1)?

Comment: In some case, email will be in the last word, but I want email parenthesis force to be the first member in array, Can I force the order in parenthesis?

Comment: @user2194507: No, you can't force order. But your requierement is not so clear, please edit your question or ask another one with sample input strings and desired result.

Comment: base on current coding

$raw  = "bk-pon@huawei-bangrak-fl5.bangkok xpon 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499";
preg_match('#^(\S+)\s\w+\s(\d+/\d+/\d+)/((\d+):\d+\.\d+\.\d+)$#', $raw, $matches);

I can access email via $matches[1]

but if the raw string change to follwing,

$raw2  = "xpon 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499 bk-pon@huawei-bangrak-fl5.bangkok ";

now email is in the last word, so after revise preg_match() function, I can access email via $matchs[4]
Is it possible when to speficific order in preg_match() so I can always access email via $matches[1] without interest the location of email?

Comment: @user2194507: No, you can't. The first group begins at the first opening parenthesis, the secnd group begins at the second opening parenthesis and so on...

Comment: OK, M42. I understood now. Your comment very helpful for me. Thank you very much. Very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, and look for `1,2,3` index from `$m`

```
$raw  = "bk-pon@huawei-bangrak-fl5.bangkok xpon 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499";
preg_match('~(\d+/\d+/\d+)/(?=(\d+))(.*)~', $raw, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0/3/0/1:4.1.3499
    [1] => 0/3/0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1:4.1.3499
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This work. Could you explain how this pattern match to group1, 2 and 3. I need to know logic? I'm very new with PHP pattern.

Comment: @user2194507 its used positive lookahead here to match the second portion.

Comment: Could you help me again, I need to run preg_match 3 times, each time will match and assign to only 1 variable and may have different pattern, I don't need it to be array. Is this possible?

Comment: Run `preg_match` once, and pick the values from array using `$slot = $m[1];`

Answer (score 1):

A good introduction for Regex can be found on http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and you can test out your regex's here: http://regexpal.com/ along with many other google links ;)

If your end of string always stays the same length, then just use PHP's `substr` method with -16 (or however many characters it is).

Otherwise you can use something like /([0-9/]+)+\:([0-9.]+)/ and then just parse out the data.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
preg_match('~(\d+/\d+/\d+)/((\d+):[^ ]*)~', $raw, $matches);
list(, $slot, $port2, $port1) = $matches;
```

output:

```
// slot
string '0/3/0' (length=5)

// port1
string '1' (length=1)

// port2
string '1:4.1.3499' (length=10)
```

Comment: Could you help me again, I need to run preg_match 3 times, each time will match and assign to only 1 variable and may have different pattern, I don't need it to be array. Is this possible?